# Accessing the request object with AssetPack in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, sinatra-assetpack

I'm using [AssetPack](http://ricostacruz.com/sinatra-assetpack/) to handle public assets on my Sinatra app. Because the app work as a embeddeable ad on sites, I need to declare css assets route absolute. This is my current code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'rack'
require 'sinatra/assetpack'

class Ads < Sinatra::Application

  assets {
    css :mybanner, "http://#{request.host_with_port}/css/styling.css", [
      "http://#{request.host_with_port}/css/styling.css"
    ]
  }
```

The problem is that when calling `request.host_with_port` I'm getting the following error

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `request' for #    <Sinatra::AssetPack::Options:0x007fc1f88b0a80>
```

I'm not sure why `request` is not working. Any idea?

Comment: It isn't working because you're calling it from outside the Sinatra app scope. If you pay attention you'd see that it is called from the `Sinatra::AssetPack::Options` instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood, *AssetPack* builds the assets at server start.
The `request` object isn't available at that time, obviously.

Here's what I'd suggest:

```
class Ads < Sinatra::Application
  host_with_port = ENV['HOST_WITH_PORT']

  assets {
    css :mybanner, "http://#{host_with_port}/css/styling.css", [
      "http://#{host_with_port}/css/styling.css"
    ]
  }
end
```

You'd need to set a `HOST_WITH_PORT` environment variable, but you'll do it only once for each site.